# Print wirelessly from USB printer connected through router

Tags: ipad, network, usb, printing

I have Canon Pixma MP198 (USB only) printer that is connected to my d'link router with usb cable.

Can I print documents wirelessly from my iPad 2? Without the need to turn on my PC if I want to print?

Any apps for this?

Note:printer isnt airprint capable

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### [Printer Pro](http://readdle.com/products/printerpro_ipad/)

You can use Printer Pro. This app will scan your network for all printers using the same services as OS X, to find all printers available rather than just AirPrint printers.

> **Compatible with any Printer (Wi-Fi and USB)**
>   Printer Pro automatically finds a printer in your wi-fi network.

<sup>You can download Printer Pro Lite for free to test if your printer is found by the app before purchase.</sup>